# NAudio / CSAudio BufferMilliseconds for WasapiCapture

Tags: c#, audio, naudio, wasapi, naudio-framework

I'm sending a `WasapiCapture device` to a class that visualises the waveform in realtime using `device.DataAvailable`.

I want to change the size of audio data that triggers DataAvailable such that it cuts the incoming stream into data of 500ms in length. Reading up on it I believe there's a `BufferMilliseconds` that should do this, however it seems to only be available for WaveInEvent (legacy WaveIn APIs) and not with WASAPI.

I'm want to know if there's another way to achieve this, or if CSAudio lets you set buffer size for Wasapi device capture?